# Linux Mint Cinnamon - Virtual Desktop (workspace) settings

Tags: linux-mint, virtual-desktop, workspace

I've a kind freshly installed Linux Mint (20.1 Ulyssa), and originally I had 4 workspaces, and I wanted to change, but it seems to be not so obvious from the GUI.

I installed some panel application which resulted to have now only one workspace (virtual desktop).

I'd like to ask what is the standard way of setting the number of workspaces with this version of Linux Mint as I can't find any.

Thanks.

---

The only one similar thing I found is the Workspace settings, but it has only a few off/on settings, which does not really help.

Answer (score 1):

Press **Control+Alt+UpArrow** It will show Workspaces preview, from where you can add and delete workspaces.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeuAu.png

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, to what Arch User said...

**Control+Alt+Left** and **Control+Alt+Right** let you switch between the workspaces on-the-fly.